# [Paas][Platform as a service][Are Online IDEs Paas]

Tags: cloud, paas

I was reading about Saas,Paas,Iaas.

My question is the online IDEs(like Ideone) we use to run programs of languages
example of Platform as a Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PaaS provides you a platform to build, test and deploy your applications on the cloud, examples of PaaS can be Microsoft Azure's Web Apps(App Service) or AWS Elastic Beanstalk‎. The online IDEs are not a platform offering of cloud services, they are just online software for writing and compiling your code. The online IDEs(like Ideone) are the examples of SaaS as they provide ready to use software, without the  need to develop, deploy or maintain them. Other exmaples of SaaS includes online tools/softwares like Microsoft Office 365, Google photos etc.